# react-native pass authentication challenge in webview

Tags: authentication, react-native, webview

I am trying to access a secure website through a WebView. When I access it through a browser, I get an Authentication Challenge. How can I show that in a WebView? Normal popups are enabled in the WebView (and they show) but this is not a regular popup, it is an Authentication Challenge

Comment: I have the same question. Basically I am looking for the equivalent of `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` or `willSendRequestForAuthentication` methods from the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol. Or `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest` for the Android world.